# How I can send data from html Form, to a nodejs Server using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, server, client

this is my form in form.html,I have to do an ajax call type post

```
<div class= "container " >

    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="id">Id</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nome</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Prezzo</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prezzo">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="invia dati" class="btn btn-primary" id="button" />
  </div>
```

Comment: What you did for sending the ajax request ?

Comment: See this example: https://gist.github.com/diorahman/1520485

Comment: I hav to do it with javascript only

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way

```
var $id = $('#id');
var $name = $('#name');
var $prezzo = $('#prezzo');


$(function(){
               $('#button').click(function(e){
                   e.preventDefault();
                   console.log('select_link clicked');

                                   var object = {
                       id:$id.val(),
                       name:$name.val(),
                       prezzo: $prezzo.val()
                     };


         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           data: JSON.stringify(object),
           contentType: 'application/json',
           url: 'http://localhost:3000/router/newProducts',
           success: function(data) {
                   console.log('success');
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
                       }
                   });

               });
           });
```